# What is the historical origin of CTRL + P for up and CTRL + N for down?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, history

I am a moderately experienced vim user, who is now beginning to use GNU emacs. At about the same time as I learned that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd> are the default for up and down in emacs, I also learned they are variants of k and j in normal mode in vim.

**Does anyone know the origin of these shortcuts?** I suppose that  logically they come from p(revious) and n(ext), or maybe (u)p and (dow)n, but I am asking about **what programme, system or standard they were part of.** It seems unlikely that a couple of random emacs shortcuts were borrowed into vim, so their inclusion in both makes me think that they probably predate both emacs and vim.*

It's hard to find the answers to questions of keystrokes using Google, but interestingly they are not mentioned as "arrow keys" on the seemingly comprehensive [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_keys).

*Thanks to Thomas Dickey and Mark Plotnick who have pointed out in comments that the shortcuts in question are documented in 1984 vi (sic), and [1978 emacs reference](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/mit/ai/aim/AIM-447.pdf) works, but I think the question of common origin still stands.

Comment: In emacs (or bash/ksh in emacs mode), I use Previous/Next as a reminder of which way to go. along Forward/Backward.

Comment: @Archemar Ah yes, that makes more sense. I've added that in as a more logical origin, but my historical question still stands :-)

Comment: They predate vim, e.g., are documented in the 1984 "vi user's handbook".

Comment: The earliest reference I can find for "n for next, p for previous" for the Emacs lineage is [AI Memo 447 - An Introduction to the EMACS editor](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/mit/ai/aim/AIM-447.pdf) from 1978. It's possible that one of Emacs' predecessors such as RMODE also used n for next and p for previous, but I couldn't find a reference.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's also mentioned in [An Introduction to Display Editing with Vi](https://docs.freebsd.org/44doc/usd/12.vi/paper.pdf), which is about as old.  It didn't come from TECO or SOS.

Comment: Control-N and P are present in a 1976 version of EMACS.  My guess is, either they were invented by Guy Steele, or they were copied from one of EMACS' predecessors: TECMAC, TMACS, etc.  (They are not from RMODE, I checked.)

Answer (score 5):

I cannot provide proof of any kind, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> belong to the `emacs` key bindings, in contrast to `vi` bindings (`bindkey -e` vs. `bindkey -v`).  Under this premise, you should look for an explanation in `emacs` itself.

`emacs`' tutorial tells

> There are several ways you can do this.  You can use the arrow keys,
>   but it's more efficient to keep your hands in the standard position
>   and use the commands C-p, C-b, C-f, and C-n.  These characters
>   are equivalent to the four arrow keys, like this:
>
> - Previous line, C-p
> - Backward, C-b
> - Forward, C-f
> - Next line, C-n

Seems inconvenient for the common `vi` user, but makes absolute sense.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> were part of TECO EMACS in 1976.  Guy Steele is credited as the progenitor of the EMACS command set, synthesizing from a number of TECO-based text editors in use at the time.  Those other editors had similar cursor movement commands, but not exactly the same.